# CSS equal height divs with padding

Tags: css

I have been using this [technique](http://www.ejeliot.com/samples/equal-height-columns/example-4.html) before to get equal column heights

```
#page-wrap { overflow: hidden;}
.page-left, .page-right{float: left; width: 435px; margin-bottom: -5000px; padding-bottom: 5000px; }
.page-left { background: #454545; }            
.page-right { background: #383838; }

<div id="page-wrap">        
    <div class="page-left">
            Blahblah<br />
            Blahblah<br />
            Blahblah<br />
    </div>    
    <div class="page-right">
            Blahblah
    </div>
    <div class="clearboth"></div>    
</div> <!-- end wrap -->
```

This works fine but now I need to put #page-wrap inside another DV with margin: 10px;
it works fine in **normal** browsers, but not in IE...

I have a Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/SyAeq/

**EDIT:**
Solved! Just adding a {float:left} to #page-wrap did the trick!
Than a {clear:left} in a div underneath to clean it up

Comment: This question might be better asked on http://doctype.com/.

Comment: If you solved it yourself, you should post it as an answer, then when the time period has expired, mark your own answer as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, solved this by adding a {float:left} to #page-wrap.
Than a {clear:left} in a div underneath to clean it up.